# Make this algorithm more efficent

Tags: php

I'm a php noob, and need some help. I've build a push service to send out push messages to an iphone. It says in the comments that it's more efficient to combine several messages into one packet. Also, right now I make a call to delete each and every message. How do I combine several messages into one package?

Thanks

```
function start()
{
    writeToLog('Connecting to ' . $this->server);

    if (!$this->connectToAPNS())
        exit;


    while (true)
    {
        // Do at most 20 messages at a time. Note: we send each message in
        // a separate packet to APNS. It would be more efficient if we 
        // combined several messages into one packet, but this script isn't
        // smart enough to do that. ;-)

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM push_queue WHERE time_sent IS NULL LIMIT 20');
        $stmt->execute();
        $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($messages as $message)
        {
            if ($this->sendNotification($message->message_id, $message->device_token, $message->payload))
            {
                //$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE push_queue SET time_sent = NOW() WHERE message_id = ?');
                //$stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id = ?');
                $stmt->execute(array($message->message_id));

            }
            else  // failed to deliver
            {
                $this->reconnectToAPNS();
            }
        }

        unset($messages);           
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question has NOTHING to do with optimizing SQL it is about whatever is done with the result of the SQL... you need to explain that part with much more detail to get usable answers!

Answer (score 4):

You can group deleted messages IDs inside array

```
$deletedIds = array()
foreach ($messages as $message)
{
    if ($this->sendNotification())
    {
        $deletedIds[] = $message->message_id;
    }
}
```

After that you can delete such messages using query method

```
$this->pdo->query('DELETE FROM push_queue WHERE message_id IN ('.implode(',', $deletedIds).')');
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Is it possible to do something similar with the message query that is being sent out?